# React native dynamic image uri

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm trying to change image uri on tap. Here's my try
the state

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
   
    selected_uri:'./assets/rock.png',
    uri: require(selected_uri)

  };
...
```

the calling point

```
//at outside render function
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => {
          let select=Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
          cs=choices[select];
          this.setState({
            selected_uri:'./assets/'+{cs}+'.png'
          });
         
           
        }}
        >
          <Text>Rock</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

And it gives this error.

```
error: App.js: App.js:Invalid call at line 21: require(selected_uri)
```

I just want to change icon on press

Comment: How can I call it in state and setstate onpress

Comment: Does it is not because you are setting the state inside one object? Try set the state outside one object. this.setState(selected_uri:'./assets/'+{cs}+'.png')

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it on a fixed image, you can use `require` as an `array`.

ex

```
state = {
  index:0,
}
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
const images = [require('./assets/rock.png'),
                require('./assets/paper.png'),
                require('./assets/scissors.png')];

render(){
   const { index } = this.state;
   const currentChoice = this.choices[index];
   const currentImage = this.images[index];
}
```

only change the index using setState.